# Token bug? when I try to list all files, folders, subfiles and folders of a google drive reader

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I use this code to list all files and folders for a Google Drive reader using the GAE SDK and the google-api-python-client. The reader in the query is an app engine service account:

```
page_token = None
param = {'q' : '"example@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" in readers'}
while True:
    try:
        page = service.files().list(**param).execute()
        for each in page.get('items', []):
            logging.info('File Id: %s' % each['title'])
        page_token = page.get('nextPageToken')
        if page_token:
            param['pageToken'] = page_token
            logging.info(param)
        else :
            break
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        logging.error('An error occurred: %s' %(error))
        break
```

The total number of items is about 160 in two pages. But the while loop never stops. After the "last" page item I keep receiving nextPageTokens, but the list of items of the next page is empty.

The GAE SDK log can be found here : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9-mEcXX8BPaQUJZZmVkWGxiZFk/edit?usp=sharing

**UPDATE, The loop stops but ...**

I added some counters for pages and items. 
After 135 pages with 165 folder and file items (165 received in the first two pages) I received a None nextPageToken. So it finally stops. 163 list requests (pages) do not report any items.

The reader has access to a single folder under the root and all the subfolders and files under this folder. So what is going on. Is this a bug?

Comment: That doesn't sound great, but I can't reproduce it. Can you put some debugging output so we can see the empty pages please?

Comment: I have already shared a part of the SDK log. See the link above : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9-mEcXX8BPaQUJZZmVkWGxiZFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I suggest to add an option, like in unix : ls -R. Now I check the token for None and I count the page results. If I receive no page results, I stop the loop.